# Update table based on another table with date condition

Tags: sql, oracle

UTILITYREADING TABLE

| ROOMNUMBER | ELECTRICITYREADING | DATEOFREADING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N201 | 279.8 | 2/15/2022 |
| N201 | 240.6 | 1/16/2022 |
| N201 | 240.6 | 12/15/2021 |
| N202 | 299.8 | 2/15/2022 |
| N202 | 259.8 | 1/15/2022 |

UTILITYINVOICE table should look like this:

| ROOMNUMBER | ELECCURRENT | ELECPREVIOUS | INVOICEDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N201 | 279.8 | 240.6 | 2/19/2022 |
| N202 | 299.8 | 259.8 | 2/19/2022 |

I was able to insert the `ELECCURRENT` value (or the current month February reading) by executing:

```
INSERT INTO UTILITYINVOICE (ROOMNUMBER, ELECCURRENT, INVOICEDATE)
    SELECT 
        ROOMNUMBER, NVL(ELECTRICITYREADING, 0), SYSDATE
    FROM UTILITYREADING 
    WHERE (extract(MONTH from DATEOFREADING) = extract(MONTH from SYSDATE)) 
      AND (extract(YEAR from DATEOFREADING) = extract(YEAR from SYSDATE));
```

My problem is fetching the February reading, to fetch the January reading i tried this but with no success:

```
UPDATE UTILITYINVOICE
SET ELECPREVIOUS = (SELECT NVL(ELECTRICITYREADING, 0)
                    FROM UTILITYREADING) 
                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM utilityreading
                                  WHERE (extract(MONTH from UTILITYREADING.DATEOFREADING) = extract(MONTH from SYSDATE)-1) 
                                    AND (extract(YEAR from UTILITYREADING.DATEOFREADING) = extract(YEAR from SYSDATE))
                                    AND utilityreading.roomnumber = utilityinvoice.roomnumber);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you need

- `LAG` analytic function (to select *previous* electricity reading)
- `ROW_NUMBER` (to *sort* rows per each room number by date in descending order)

  - and then fetch row that ranks as the *highest*

---

```
SQL> insert into utilityinvoice (roomnumber, eleccurrent, elecprevious, invoicedate)
  2  with temp as
  3    (select roomnumber,
  4       electricityreading as eleccurrent,
  5       lag(electricityreading) over (partition by roomnumber order by dateofreading) elecprevious,
  6       row_number() Over (partition by roomnumber order by dateofreading desc) rn
  7     from utilityreading
  8    )
  9  select roomnumber, eleccurrent, elecprevious, sysdate
 10  from temp
 11  where rn = 1;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from utilityinvoice;

ROOM ELECCURRENT ELECPREVIOUS INVOICEDAT
---- ----------- ------------ ----------
N201       279,8        240,6 02/19/2022
N202       299,8        259,8 02/19/2022

SQL>
```

Comment: hi littlefoot thanks for your answer,,, can you revise it to fetch only the latest month for the eleccurrent and the previous month for the elecprevious?? some records on the utilityreading table are not updated if there are no tenants so old records should not be included..thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: You're welcome. Include WHERE clause, e.g. `where dateofreading >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1)`

Comment: (select roomnumber,
electricityreading as eleccurrent,
lag(electricityreading) over (partition by roomnumber order by dateofreading) elecprevious,
row_number() Over (partition by roomnumber order by dateofreading desc) rn
from utilityreading where dateofreading >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1)
 )
select roomnumber, eleccurrent, elecprevious, sysdate
from temp
where rn = 1;

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.